# Too many connections from other IP addresses and my own IP address

Tags: networking, ubuntu, connection, iptables

I get thousands of connections from same IPs. It takes down my web server (Apache). How could I restrict 1 ip to open only 10 connections max using ip table rules?

My 2nd issue is there are so many connections from my own server to my server ip. I use the following command to count the connections:

```
netstat -an | grep tcp | awk '{print $6}' | cut -f 1 -d : | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Output:

```
 1 FIN_WAIT2
      2 CLOSE_WAIT
      3 LAST_ACK
     21 FIN_WAIT1
     36 LISTEN
    136 ESTABLISHED
   18692 TIME_WAIT
```

I used a different command (below) to see which IP has the max connections:

```
netstat -an | grep tcp | awk '{print $5}' | cut -f 1 -d : | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Output

```
.....
     17 122.176.38.209
     20
     20 0.0.0.0
  17530 MY_Server_IP
```

Someone is trying to use hundreds of IPs to open so many connections (hundreds per ip) to take down my server. Why my server is opening connections to itself and in time_wait? What can I do to protect this?

Is there a way to kill all the time_wait connections at once?

Comment: What port are the connections on? What is listening there?

Comment: Can you include some samples of your server connecting to itself?  The answer is not to kill this sessions, but to understand why they are forming and stop them if they are invalid.

Comment: Paul, which command can I use to get this info? @SamiKuhmonen, it's on port 80.